# Javascript: object key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key-value

I am trying to get the output like:-

```
[{"option_id":1,"name":"small"},{"option_id":1,"name":"medium"}]
```

Below is my snippet, as you can see console.log only display single object instead of two. Why is that? :/

```js
const myObject = {
  "'\1\'": "small",
  "'\1\'": "medium"
};

var item = [];

Object.entries(myObject).forEach(([k, v]) => {
  item.push({
    name: v,
    option_id: k
  });

  console.log(item);
})
```

Comment: because your object has duplicate keys, the first pair will be overwritten

Comment: but that how my json output looks like, is there any ways for it @RameshReddy?

Comment: If you JSON looks like that (with duplicate keys), then you should process it as a string and parse each element yourself. Once you have an object, duplicate keys will be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are using just overrides the duplicate keys you created  ... to prevent this situation do not use object keys ! you can rely on the arrays passing the data you want

See example =>

```
const myObject = {
  // number : [name , option]
  0: ["small", 1],
  1: ["medium", 1]
};

let item = [];

Object.entries(myObject).forEach(obj => {
  item.push({
    name: obj[1][0],
    option_id: obj[1][1]
  });
})

console.log(item);
```

**Best way using array methods**

```
let  myObject = [
  ["small", 1],
  ["medium", 1]
];

myObject = myObject.map(obj => {
  return {
    name: obj[0], option_id: obj[1]};
});

console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: @cdogol Try this one I think it will help you for sure !

Comment: Hey @Sanmeet thanks for your help! I got the idea from your answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a JSON formatted string, then use the JSON libraries to work on the string.

```
const myObject = {
  1: "small",
  1: "medium"
};

var item = [];

Object.entries(myObject).forEach(([k, v]) => {
  item.push('{"name":"' + v + '", "option_id":"' + k + '"}');
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse('[' + item.join(",") + ']')));
```

Comment: Hi @HeathSmith, i tried your code on fiddle but it says script error.

Comment: There's an error please try solving it and revise your answer !